# Spark streaming : how can a apply a window on dataframe using java

Tags: java, dataframe, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

how can i recover data: foreach 15 minutes i want to recover the data of the passed 15 minutes.
If i'm at 14H:00 i have to recover data from 13H:45 to 14H.

I tried

```java
Dataset<Row> df = mydf
   .withWatermark("timestamp","15 minutes")
   .groupBy(window(col("timestamp"), "15 minutes", "15 minutes"),col("value")).count();
```

but it doesn't works, someone who has an idea please, thanks

Comment: I just read a book where someone was doing this with `PySpark`, so it's possible. But I can't remind how. I remind having seen usage of methods `log(..)` and `over(...)`. Good luck ! And hope someone with far more knowledge than me will help you !

Comment: can you explain what is not working? do you get an error or is it processing the wrong data? Can you print the schema of `mydf`?

Comment: it not working as expected.it not returns me data in the window.the schema is : |-- key: binary (nullable = true)
 |-- value: binary (nullable = true)
 |-- topic: string (nullable = true)
 |-- partition: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- offset: long (nullable = true)
 |-- timestamp: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- timestampType: integer (nullable = true)